# graphic buffer allocation

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to put together a simple app that can take an existing file on the sd card and email it as a backup to a content provider scenario. Having a couple of issues- the most troubling is I keep getting these graphic buffer allocation errors- it looks like when trying to call the second activity the Graphic Buffer Allocation is using up all the memory, but I don't know why. I have read that there have been bugs reported for this issue on the phone I am testing on (Galaxy Nexus), but I am pretty much using default graphics on the UI- it's very basic, so I'm not sure why this is happening. Also I am new at this so please pardon me if I am overlooking something very obvious on these.

The code and error log (edited for length as it is cyclical and very long) with the pertinent errors is below. I appreciate any help and/ or guidance- thank you.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
/**
 * This class runs in the event that the Content provider
 * step fails. This looks for the existing file generated by the
 * content class, prepares the file, and hands the file
 * to the SendData class to be emailed.
 */
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity_VADataSender";
public static String MyDB;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
        {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
        }

    // Create the getData intent
    Intent intentgetData;

    // call the life cycle events
    // for now, inherit the settings from the parent class
    // replace these with specifics if necessary once program is operational
    public void onPause()
        {
        super.onPause();
        }

    public void onResume()
        {
        super.onResume();
        }

    public void onStop()
        {
        super.onStop();
        }

    public void onDestroy()
        { 
        super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override 
        public void onStart() 
        {
            intentgetData = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SendData.class);
            startActivity(intentgetData);
        super.onStart();
        }
        public MainActivity() throws FileMissingException   
        {           
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) 
                {
                // verify the paths-  NOTE: may be device-specific 
                String currentDBPath = "TLC_COMMON/database.txt"; 
                String backupDBPath = "database.txt"; 
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) 
                // make the connection  
                    try
                    //set the connections
                    {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();

                    // use the actual file name here (not backupDB)
                    setMyDB(backupDB);          
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e)
                    // if connection error
                        {
                        Log.e(TAG, "ERROR 1: current database does not exist"); 
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        this.finish();
                        // halt processing  
                        throw new FileMissingException();
                        } 
                }
                else
                // if sd can not write  
                    {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ERROR 2: SD is not writable");
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                        //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    this.finish(); 
                    throw new FileMissingException();
                    }
            // returned at line 102
            //return MyDB;
        }


        // same here- get the actual file name
    public void setMyDB(File backupDB) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static Object getMyDB() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return MyDB;
    }   
}
    </CODE>
```

Second class:

```
    public class SendData extends MainActivity
{
public SendData() throws FileMissingException {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private static final String TAG = "SendData_VADatasender";

/* Checks if external storage is available to read */   
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() 
    {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) 
        {
        return true;
        }
        {       
        return false;
        }
    }   

// Send data by email
    public void dataGetter() throws FileMissingException
    {
        try
        {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        // verify it is saving as this file name; also path in previous class
        String fileName = "MyDB";

            {
                if (sd.canWrite()) 
                    { 
                    // add the File Attachment and URI (in EXTRA_TEXT) below once the program is running
            //is this redundant to Object attachment below?
                    File attachment = new File(fileName); 
                    }   
                else 
                    {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Email attachment failed");
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                            //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    finish();
                    }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        Log.e(TAG,"ERROR 5: Could not locate file"); 
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        finish();
        throw new FileMissingException();
        }
    }

        Intent email;

        @Override
        public void onStart(){
        //Uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), MyDB));
            {
        Object attachment = MainActivity.getMyDB();

                { 
            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Exercise data");
            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"vamedstudy@gmail.com"});
            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, (Boolean) (attachment)); //Uri.fromFile(attachment)
            //email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse((String) attachment));
            //email.setType("message/rfc822");
            email.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send the exercise data:"));  
            super.onStart();
                }
            }   
        }   

    public void finish() 
        {   
        }   
    }
```

```
ERROR LOG:

11-21 12:21:54.367: I/ActivityManager(2448): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=

[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.va.datasender/.MainActivity 

u=0} from pid 2640
11-21 12:21:54.468: E/MainActivity_VADataSender(4040): ERROR: current database does not exist
11-21 12:21:54.492: I/ActivityManager(2448): START {act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER 

cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity (has extras) u=0} from pid 4040
11-21 12:21:54.500: I/ActivityManager(2448): START {cmp=com.example.va.datasender/.SendData 

u=0} from pid 4040
11-21 12:21:54.585: E/MainActivity_VADataSender(4040): ERROR: current database does not exist

....repeats...then graphics errors

11-21 12:21:57.265: I/ActivityManager(2448): START {cmp=com.example.va.datasender/.SendData 

u=0} from pid 4040
11-21 12:21:57.359: E/IMGSRV(121): :0: PVRSRVAllocDeviceMem: Error 1 returned
11-21 12:21:57.359: E/IMGSRV(121): :0: GenericAlloc: Failed to allocate device memory
11-21 12:21:57.359: W/GraphicBufferAllocator(121): alloc(720, 1184, 5, 00000b00, ...) failed -

12 (Out of memory)
11-21 12:21:57.359: D/GraphicBufferAllocator(121): Allocated buffers:
11-21 12:21:57.359: D/GraphicBufferAllocator(121): 0x40b0cc40: 3404.00 KiB |  720 ( 736) x 1184 

|        5 | 0x00000b00
11-21 12:21:57.359: D/GraphicBufferAllocator(121): 0x40b1e6d8: 3404.00 KiB |  720 ( 736) x 1184 

|        5 | 0x00000b00
11-21 12:21:57.359: D/GraphicBufferAllocator(121): 0x40bb5898: 3404.00 KiB |  720 ( 736) x 1184 

|        5 | 0x00000b00
11-21 12:21:57.359: D/GraphicBufferAllocator(121): 0x40bb5a90: 3404.00 KiB |  720 ( 736) x 1184 

|        5 | 0x00000b00
11-21 12:21:57.359: D/GraphicBufferAllocator(121): 0x40bb5f18: 3404.00 KiB |  720 ( 736) x 1184 

|        5 | 0x00000b00
11-21 12:21:57.359: D/GraphicBufferAllocator(121): 0x40bb6ec8: 3404.00 KiB |  720 ( 736) x 1184 

|        5 | 0x00000b00
11-21 12:21:57.359: D/GraphicBufferAllocator(121): 0x40bba990: 1213.25 KiB |  720 ( 736) x  422 

|        1 | 0x00000933
11-21 12:21:57.359: D/GraphicBufferAllocator(121): 0x40bbb428: 3404.00 KiB |  720 ( 736) x 1184 

|        5 | 0x00000b00
...
11-21 12:21:57.359: D/GraphicBufferAllocator(121): 0x40c06b58: 1279.38 KiB |  720 ( 736) x  445 

|        1 | 0x00000933
11-21 12:21:57.359: D/GraphicBufferAllocator(121): 0x40c0e778:  143.75 KiB |  720 ( 736) 
11-21 12:21:57.359: E/SurfaceFlinger(121): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=720, 

h=1184) failed (Out of memory), handle=0x0
11-21 12:21:57.359: E/BufferQueue(121): 

[com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData] dequeueBuffer: 

SurfaceComposer::createGraphicBuffer failed
11-21 12:21:57.359: E/IMGSRV(4040): :0: DequeueLockStoreBuffer: Failed to de-queue buffer
11-21 12:21:57.359: W/HardwareRenderer(4040): EGL error: EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW
11-21 12:21:57.375: W/HardwareRenderer(4040): Mountain View, we've had a problem here. 

Switching back to software rendering.

...then out of memory errors...

11-21 12:21:57.453: E/SurfaceFlinger(121): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=720, 

h=1184) failed (Out of memory), handle=0x0
11-21 12:21:57.453: E/BufferQueue(121): 

[com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData] dequeueBuffer: 

SurfaceComposer::createGraphicBuffer failed
11-21 12:21:57.453: E/IMGSRV(4040): :0: DequeueLockStoreBuffer: Failed to de-queue buffer
11-21 12:21:57.453: E/libEGL(4040): eglMakeCurrent:534 error 3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040): OutOfResourcesException initializing HW surface
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040): android.view.Surface$OutOfResourcesException: 

eglMakeCurrent failed EGL_BAD_ALLOC
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at android.view.HardwareRenderer

$GlRenderer.createEglSurface(HardwareRenderer.java:920)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at android.view.HardwareRenderer

$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:748)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals

(ViewRootImpl.java:1505)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal

(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl

$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at android.view.Choreographer

$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks

(Choreographer.java:555)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame

(Choreographer.java:525)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at android.view.Choreographer

$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback

(Handler.java:615)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage

(Handler.java:92)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main

(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native 

Method)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke

(Method.java:511)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit

$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main

(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-21 12:21:57.460: E/ViewRootImpl(4040):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 

Method)
11-21 12:21:57.460: I/Process(4040): Sending signal. PID: 4040 SIG: 9
11-21 12:21:57.460: I/WindowManager(2448): Out of memory for surface!  Looking for leaks...
11-21 12:21:57.460: W/WindowManager(2448): No leaked surfaces; killing applicatons!
11-21 12:21:57.460: W/ActivityManager(2448): Killing processes Free memory at adjustment 5
11-21 12:21:57.460: W/ViewRootImpl(4040): No processes killed for memory; killing self
11-21 12:21:57.500: I/WindowState(2448): WIN DEATH: Window{41d5aa70 

com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData paused=false}
11-21 12:21:57.500: W/WindowManager(2448): Due to memory failure, waiting a bit for next layout
11-21 12:21:57.500: W/InputDispatcher(2448): channel '41da3af0 

com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData (server)' ~ Consumer closed input 

channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
11-21 12:21:57.500: E/InputDispatcher(2448): channel '41da3af0 

com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData (server)' ~ Channel is 

unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-21 12:21:57.500: I/ActivityManager(2448): Process com.example.va.datasender (pid 4040) has 

died.
11-21 12:21:57.507: W/ActivityManager(2448): Force removing ActivityRecord{41e80dd0 

com.example.va.datasender/.SendData}: app died, no saved state
11-21 12:21:57.757: W/InputDispatcher(2448): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input 

channel '41da3af0 com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData (server)'
11-21 12:21:57.757: I/WindowState(2448): WIN DEATH: Window{41da3af0 

com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData paused=false}
11-21 12:21:57.773: I/WindowState(2448): WIN DEATH: Window{41deb038 

com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData paused=false}
11-21 12:21:57.773: I/WindowState(2448): WIN DEATH: Window{41e75500 

com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData paused=false}
11-21 12:21:57.773: I/WindowState(2448): WIN DEATH: Window{41d296a8 

com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData paused=false}
11-21 12:21:57.781: I/WindowState(2448): WIN DEATH: Window{41ca39c8 

com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData paused=false}
11-21 12:21:57.781: I/WindowState(2448): WIN DEATH: Window{41a35a18 

com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData paused=false}
com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData paused=false}
11-21 12:21:57.804: W/InputDispatcher(2448): channel '41caaec8 

com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData (server)' ~ Consumer closed input 

channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
11-21 12:21:57.804: E/InputDispatcher(2448): channel '41caaec8 

com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData (server)' ~ Channel is 

unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

...then worse errors...

11-21 12:21:57.828: I/WindowState(2448): WIN DEATH: Window{41dd0130 

com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData paused=false}
11-21 12:21:57.835: E/InputDispatcher(2448): Received spurious receive callback for unknown 

input channel.  fd=244, events=0x9
11-21 12:21:57.835: E/InputDispatcher(2448): Received spurious receive callback for unknown 

input channel.  fd=225, events=0x9
11-21 12:21:57.835: E/InputDispatcher(2448): Received spurious receive callback for unknown 

input channel.  fd=217, events=0x9
11-21 12:21:57.835: E/InputDispatcher(2448): Received spurious receive callback for unknown 

input channel.  fd=258, events=0x9
11-21 12:21:57.835: E/InputDispatcher(2448): Received spurious receive callback for unknown 

input channel.  fd=259, events=0x9
11-21 12:21:57.835: E/InputDispatcher(2448): Received spurious receive callback for unknown 

input channel.  fd=260, events=0x9

...then it crashes...

11-21 12:21:57.843: W/ActivityManager(2448): Force removing ActivityRecord{41714778 

com.example.va.datasender/.SendData}: app died, no saved state
11-21 12:21:57.843: W/ActivityManager(2448): Force removing ActivityRecord{41a69f30 

com.example.va.datasender/.SendData}: app died, no saved state
11-21 12:21:57.843: W/ActivityManager(2448): Force removing ActivityRecord{41c65b30 

com.example.va.datasender/.SendData}: app died, no saved state
11-21 12:21:57.859: D/dalvikvm(4289): Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-21 12:21:57.859: I/ActivityManager(2448): Displayed com.example.va.datasender/.SendData: 

+3s356ms (total +3s395ms)
11-21 12:21:57.859: I/ActivityManager(2448): Displayed com.example.va.datasender/.SendData: 

+3s149ms
11-21 12:21:57.859: I/ActivityManager(2448): Displayed com.example.va.datasender/.SendData: 

+1s657ms
11-21 12:21:57.859: I/ActivityManager(2448): Displayed com.example.va.datasender/.SendData: 

+2s540ms
11-21 12:21:57.859: I/ActivityManager(2448): Displayed com.example.va.datasender/.SendData: 

+977ms

...leaked surface errors...

11-21 12:21:58.343: W/WindowManager(2448): LEAKED SURFACE (app token hidden): Window{41d2df50 

com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData paused=false} surface=Surface

(name=com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData, identity=1350) 

token=AppWindowToken{41cc7c48 token=Token{4198ba08 ActivityRecord{41ca22a8 

com.example.va.datasender/.SendData}}}
11-21 12:21:58.343: W/WindowManager(2448): LEAKED SURFACE (app token hidden): Window{41d5e1b0 

com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData paused=false} surface=Surface

(name=com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.SendData, identity=1351) 

token=AppWindowToken{41c78878 token=Token{419e78f8 ActivityRecord{41cd1208 

com.example.va.datasender/.SendData}}}
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that your graphic memory is not enough. reboot your phone will resolve this problem.